# Concat column of one table to each column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have dates in one table:

```
2021-10-01
2021-10-02
```

And codes in another table:

```
0101
0102
```

I want my results to look like so:

```
2021-10-01 - 0101
2021-10-02 - 0101
2021-10-01 - 0102
2021-10-01 - 0102
```

Which translates to adding all codes to each date into a final table where each date has a code.

Date table query:

```
Select DATE from Table1
```

Code table query:

```
Select CODE from Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a cross join:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.date, 120) + ' - ' + t2.code
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
ORDER BY t2.code, t1.date;
```

### Demo